# React Jest: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am new to react and have a failing test which i am not able to understand whether it's a class import issue or I am not sending required params correctly.

Here is my code

```
import * as React from 'react'
import cx from 'classnames'
import './dropdown.scss'

export interface DropdownProps {
    options: {
        key: string
        text: string
        value: string
    }[]
    value?: string
    placeholder?: string
    onSelect?: (value: string) => any
    children?: React.ReactNode
}

export const Dropdown = ({ options, value, placeholder, onSelect }: DropdownProps) => {
    const hasValue = typeof value === 'string';

    const [ top, setTop ] = React.useState(0);
    const handleTriggerRef = (el: HTMLButtonElement) => {
        if (el) {
            setTop(el.clientHeight)
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={cx('dropdown-container')}>
            <button
                className={cx('title', { hasValue: hasValue })}
                ref={handleTriggerRef}
                onClick={() => {
                    if (value && typeof onSelect === 'function') {
                        onSelect(value)
                    }
                }}
            >{hasValue ?
                options.filter(item => item.value === value)[0].text :
                (placeholder || 'Select value')}</button>
            <div
                style={{ top }}
                className={cx('options')}
            >
                {options.map(option =>
                    <div
                        key={option.key}
                        className={cx('option')}
                        onClick={() => {
                            onSelect(option.value)
                        }}
                    ><div className={cx('text')}>{option.text}</div></div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

And here is the test

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme/build";
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "../dropdown";

describe('Dropdown component', () => {
  test("Renders correctly", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Dropdown />);

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: ```options: {
        key: string
        text: string
        value: string
    }[]
```

I am passing here and code is working properly, it's just test which is failing.
I guess It's because i am not passing the option in the dropdown from test

Comment: Probably I need to do something like this 

```const wrapper = shallow(<Dropdown placeholder={placeholder}
                                      options={options}
                                      onSelect={setValue}
                                      value={value} />);
```
In the test

Comment: exactly, you need to pass props to be able to access them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are not passing `options` to your `Dropdown` component.

The following will prevent the error.

```
{options && options.map(option => .....
```

But what you really will also want to do in your jest test is

```
<Dropdown options={options} />;
```

Comment: Yeah, but the main thing what i am struggling with is that how can i use my `DropdownProps` interface in the test?

I can not just pass options as it will throw `ReferenceError: options is not defined`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean . Your `DropdownProps` are just describing the props that you are passing. Also, the `options` are not defined with a `?` so you need to pass them. You don't need to use these props in the test, the interface is defined in the component so that is enough. I would be surprised if it throws an error if you pass all the necessary props. Also, if you put a `?` in your `options?: ...` then TS will complain and force you do do `options && options.map...`

Comment: Yeah I tried passing `options={options}` but it's throwing `ReferenceError: options is not defined` error :P

Comment: have you defined `options` in your test? You will need to create a dummy options like `options={[{key: 1, text: 'One', value: '1'}]}`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using hooks it is recommended that we should use **mount** instead of **shallow**.

The error you are getting is because props are not passed to shallow render.

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme/build";
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "../dropdown";

describe('Dropdown component', () => {
  // no need to pass the optional props
  const props = {
    options: [{ key: 'key',text: 'text',value: 'value'}],
    value: 'value',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    onSelect: jest.fn(),
    children: <div>test</div>
  }

  test("Renders correctly", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Dropdown {...props}/>);
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```